# In measuring relay contact resistance, should I use 4 wire measurement or calculate it using the voltage across the relay and current?

Tags: relay, resistance, current-measurement, contact

I'm reading mixed things online where a current from a typical ohmmeter is too low to accurately tell us the true resistance of the relay contacts.

I've got a 30V 2.5A power supply, electronic load, and an Agilent 3458A meter at my disposal.

The relays under test have a max carry current of 1.3A

Comment: The two things you mention in the title are not mutually exclusive. You do both: you measure voltage obtained from a known current and apply current in a different cable pair, hence 4 wire measurement.

Comment: Measuring relay contact resistance is going to be difficult. That's like measuring the weight of a feather with a [historic scale](https://previews.123rf.com/images/olivierl/olivierl1403/olivierl140300010/26952182-ancien-poids-antique-type-de-balance-en-laiton-%C3%A9chelle-de-mesure-avec-des-plateaux-de-pes%C3%A9e-et-base-en-b.jpg). It's not impossible, just a tad difficult. - Do you care about the actual resistance, or do you care if it is less than X ohms?

Comment: @vangelo that is true, but I've read from Panasonic that you should use higher currents for relays with higher carry current ratings. So I've got a relay rated for a carry current of 1.5A, and Panasonic suggests injecting a current of 1A to calculate the contact resistance. A TE pdf I found online also states that I should inject a higher current than your typical ohmmeter, and I'm not sure if 4 wire measurement would suffice

Comment: @HarrySvensson I want it to be less than 0.5 ohms

Comment: I'm not sure what you're thinking a 4-wire measurement is.  Four wires is four wires.  Two, supplying 1A, and two, reading some small number of mV.  That's four.

Comment: @TimWescott thanks for the response. I actually didn't know that the current lead supplied that much current, I thought it was significantly less. Thank you for the information and clarification

Comment: Could you share the link to the document from Panasonic in your question?

Comment: @TimWescott our 3458A from Agilent only outputs 10mA for the test condition we're looking at while Panasonic suggests us to go up to 1A. Not sure what to do. Thanks again for the help

Comment: @vangelo https://www.panasonic-electric-works.com/pew/eu/downloads/ds_x61_en_relay_technical_information.pdf

Thank you again

Comment: @PP Thanks. What accuracy is required in the measurement?

Comment: So, the particular 4-wire *instrument* you have is insufficient to the task.  That doesn't make a 4-wire *measurement* a bad thing.  It just means that you need a different instrument, or you need to do it by hand.  I.e., a low-voltage, high-current supply, an ammeter, a sensitive voltmeter, and some wire.  Just like a physics lab back in school.

Comment: You just need a supply that can drive enough current that the small resistance you're measuring will produce a voltage drop that you can measure with sufficient accuracy, but still low enough current that you're not affecting the resistance you're trying to measure by heating it - that then determines the magnitude of the voltage you need to measure. For the large multipoint silver contacts in multi-kA circuit breakers, that had a contact resistance of under 10 microohms, we used a 100A source, which still means trying to measure a millivolt or less with accuracy.

Comment: I'm not so sure the instrument you have is inadequate. At 10mA and 8.5 digits you've got as much resolution as you have at 1A and 6.5 digits. The contact behavior might be a bit different at 10mA than at 1A though. 10mA at 0.5 ohms is 5mV which is a **lot** of voltage for a meter of that caliber.

Comment: @vangelo i just need it to accurately read up to 3 decimal places so 1 mohm.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany The test I'm conducting will fail the given relay when its contact resistance hits 0.5 ohms, but from some simple testing, our 4 wire instrument measured 0.07 ohms. At a current output of 10mA from the instrument, would this measurement be reliable?

Comment: What's your allowable error on the 500m\$\Omega\$ limit? I suspect it's fine if you're only looking for a rough cutoff point- 10mA is sufficient wetting current for most contacts especially if they have not been worn by much higher currents.  Waste of nice meter though, pains me.

Comment: I think +- 0.01 ohms is okay. I'm planning to run this contact resistance test every few thousand operations given a set of test conditions. One test condition requires us to put as high as 4A through the relay. You think this would make our instrument less reliable?

Comment: @PP your 3458A gives you more than enough accuracy but, considering everything that was discussed, a measurement under load seems more appropriate to include effects from contact wear, dirt and temperature issues. If you require more guidance, kindly update your question giving more detail on the equipment you have available for the tests (power source, other meters, ability to assemble a simple electronic circuit etc.)

Comment: @vangelo I think I'm going to go with using a load to measure the contact resistance. Out of curiosity, why would conducting the test under load be more appropriate to include those effects? I understand that utilizing a higher current will allow me to measure the voltage, but this seems to be able to measure the voltage across the relay fine with its small current output

Comment: From everything that was described we can assume that, as the contact ages, its parasitic resistance will grow. Larger resistance in operating conditions (higher current) also means higher temperature, that would lead to even higher resistance that would be measured at lower temperatures. Summary: resistance measured in operating conditions is likely higher than the one measured with just 10mA.

Answer (score 2):

In the image below, from the document you mention, if you connect a voltmeter close to the contact you are measuring, you are performing a 4-wire measurement. The high current does not circulate through the voltmeter cables.

If you don't want to do this with this crude setup (variable resistor) you can improve it by implementing a current source (which is quite simple) or use a bench power supply with this feature.

By using any of these 2 options with current sources you can use your *very* precise bench meter to measure both the current and voltage.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> **In measuring relay contact resistance, should I use 4 wire measurement or calculate it using the voltage across the relay and current?**

They are the same thing. A 4 wire resistance measurement measures the voltage across the unknown, while applying a current *through a different set of contacts* to the voltage measurement.

You can do this manually on the bench with a current power supply, voltmeter and ammeter, or you can use a '4 wire resistance measurement meter' which integrates those elements, and bundles 'ease of use' into it as well.

With an unpackaged relay, you could measure the voltage directly across the contacts, and get the pure contact resistance. If it's a packaged relay, the best you are going to be able to measure is the contact resistance plus the connections from the contacts to the closest you can get the voltage leads, the package terminals.